# jQuery How to set CSS transform property to any object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transforms

I need to set  transform ( transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 4, -16, -160) ) css property using jquery. from that matrix(2, 0, 0, 4, -16, -160 ) i just need to modify second last value .. I am implementing zoom plugin in my application. If i swipe on image i should be able to get those tranform matrix values, manipulate the second last one and set back tranform matrix property. i am getting tranform values, i manipulated it to the value i want . Now i just need to set that tranform property back Anyone knows? Pls help.

Comment: ^This. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Sounds straightforward. What have you tried and why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

you can use as .

```
$("#yourselectorId").css({
    transform:" matrix(2, 0, 0, 4, -16, -160)"
});
```